# Specification of class name when invoking findClass in Java Custom Class loader

Tags: java, class

In a customer class loader, I have a method findClass as follows:

```
 public Class findClass(String className){
    byte classByte[];
    Class result=null;
    result = (Class)classes.get(className);
    if(result != null){
        return result;
    }


    try{
        return findSystemClass(className);
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
    try{
       String classPath =    
  ((String)ClassLoader.getSystemResource(className.replace('.',File.separatorChar)+".class").getFile()).substring(1);
       classByte = loadClassData(classPath);
        result = defineClass(className,classByte,0,classByte.length,null);
        classes.put(className,result);
        return result;
    }catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    } 
}
```

How do I specify the name of a class that I'm trying to find if the class is in the default package.   For example, if the class is named `myclass.class`, how do I pass this name to this method.   Calling it as `findClass("myclass")` or `findClass("myclass.class")`doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `findClass("mypackage.MyClass") `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with fully qualified name: `findClass("mypackage.MyClass")`

Comment: Because the class is in the default package, there is no package to specify.   The class is in a jar.   If the jar is "Myjar.jar" and the class is "Myclass.class", how would I specify the name of the class assuming it is not in a package other than the default package.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's due to a problem with the name you're giving, ensure it has proper package prefixes.

That method given a string like "java.lang.String" will look for the file "java/lang/String.class" (on a unix file system). You may need to check the folder directory/package name of the class you're trying to load.

It's package name separated by dots and then just the class name, example:

```
 Class.forName("java.lang.String");
```

or

```
Class.forName("myclass");
```

Comment: Because the class is in the default package, there is no package to specify.   The class is in a jar.   If the jar is "Myjar.jar" and the class is "Myclass.class", how would I specify the name of the class assuming it is not in a package other than the default package.